# How do I create field collection of/in another field collection programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

How can I create field collection in another field collection using Drupal 7 Entity?

The field structure is given below;

Content type: Properties

- field_1
- field_2
- field_collection_1 (**I can create this field collection with the below fields**)

  - field_1

  - field_2

  - field_collection_2 (**But I cannot create/edit this field**)

Code which I'm using to create the field_collection_1.

```
$fc_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', ['field_name' => 'field_property_options_col']);
$fc_item->setHostEntity('node', $property);
$fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $fc_item);
$fc_wrapper->field_room_name->set($roomName);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Any idea why the code you don't show us isn't working? Please update your question so we can help you to move on.

Comment: @leymannx Apologies, the code added which I'm using to create the field collection for the desired node.